# Select from a concatenation of two columns after a left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select

### **Problem description**

Let the tables C and V have those values

```
                 >> Table V <<
| UnID | BillID |       ProductDesc        |   Value  | ... |
|   1  |    1   |      'Orange Juice'      |    3.05  | ... |
|   1  |    1   |       'Apple Juice'      |    3.05  | ... |
|   1  |    2   |          'Pizza'         |   12.05  | ... |
|   1  |    2   |        'Chocolates'      |    9.98  | ... |
|   1  |    2   |          'Honey'         |   15.98  | ... |
|   1  |    3   |          'Bread'         |    3.98  | ... |
|   2  |    1   |          'Yogurt'        |    8.55  | ... |
|   2  |    1   |        'Ice Cream'       |    7.05  | ... |
|   2  |    1   |          'Beer'          |    9.98  | ... |
|   2  |    2   |  'League of Legends RP'  |   40.00  | ... |

               >> Table C <<
| UnID | BillID |    ClientName   |  ... |
|   1  |    1   |    'Alexander'  |  ... |
|   1  |    2   |      'Tom'      |  ... |
|   1  |    3   |      'Julia'    |  ... |
|   2  |    1   |       'Tom'     |  ... |
|   2  |    2   |    'Alexander'  |  ... |
```

Table C have the values of each product, which is associated with a bill number. Table V has the relationship between the client name and the bill number. However, the bill number has a counter that is dependent on the UnId, which is the store unity ID. That being said, each store has it`s own Bill number 1, number 2, etc. Also, the number of bills from each store are not equal.

### Solution description

I'm trying to make select between the C left join V without sucess. Because each BillID is dependent on the UnID, I have to make the join considering the concatenation between those two columns. 
I've used this script, but it gives me an error.

```
SELECT
   SUM(C.Value),
   V.ClientName
FROM
   C
LEFT JOIN
   V
ON 
   CONCAT(C.UnID, C.BillID) = CONCAT(V.UnID, V.BillID)
GROUP BY
   V.ClientName
```

and SQL server returns me this `'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name`.
I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Is the use of CONCAT wrong? Or is it the way I tried to SELECT? Could you give me a hand?

[OBS: The tables I've present you are just for the purpose of explaining my difficulties. That being said, if you find any errors in the explanation, please let me know to correct them.]

Comment: it will be concat not concant

Comment: CONCAT was introduced in SQL Server 2012

Comment: Concat is for string data, not for integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be joining on the equality of the `UnID` and `BillID` columns in the two tables:

```
SELECT
    c.ClientName,
    COALESCE(SUM(v.Value), 0) AS total
FROM C c
LEFT JOIN V v
    ON c.UnID = v.UnID AND
       c.BillID = v.BillID
GROUP BY
    c.ClientName;
```

In *theory* you could try joining on `CONCAT(UnID, BillID)`.  However, you could run into problems.  For example, `UnID = 1` with `BillID = 23` would, concatenated together, be the same as `UnID = 12` and `BillID = 3`.

Note: We wrap the sum with `COALESCE`, because should a given client have no entries in the `V` table, the sum would return `NULL`, which we then replace with zero.

Answer (score 0):

concat is only available in sql server 2012.

Here's one option.

```
SELECT
   SUM(C.Value),
   V.ClientName
FROM
   C
LEFT JOIN
   V
ON 
   cast(C.UnID as varchar(100)) + cast(C.BillID as varchar(100)) = cast(V.UnID as varchar(100)) + cast(V.BillID as varchar(100))
GROUP BY
   V.ClientName
```